# Hibernate @Check annotation not working at the field level

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

[image: constraint list]I used @Check annotation at the field level, but hibernate not creates check constraints on the database. I researched that this is a bug, and @Check annotation can only be used once and at the class level. Ok, but how can I add multiple constraints at the class level? I don't want to add all conditions to the same constraint.

```
@Entity
public class TemplateTest{

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(precision = 5, scale = 2, nullable = false)
    @Check(constraints = "AMOUNT > 0")
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Check(constraints = "DISPLAY_ORDER > 0")
    private int displayOrder;

}
```

vs

```
@Entity
@Check(constraints = "DISPLAY_ORDER > 0 and AMOUNT > 0")
public class TemplateTest{

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(precision = 5, scale = 2, nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int displayOrder;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use the `columnDefinition` property of `@Column` annotation:

```java
@Entity
public class TemplateTest{

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(precision = 5, scale = 2, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "bigint check(AMOUNT > 0)")
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "bigint check(DISPLAY_ORDER > 0)")
    private int displayOrder;
}
```

2. As an alternative, you can use an [importing script file](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation-script-files) for adding additional constraints.

> To customize the schema generation process, the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files` configuration property must be used to provide other scripts files that Hibernate can use when the `SessionFactory` is started.

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="schema-generation.sql" />
```

> Hibernate is going to execute the script file after the schema is automatically generated.

Comment: I don't want to override datatype which hibernate generates, maybe I will use another Relational Database.

Comment: @SeymurAsadov As an alternative, you can use an importing script file (see my updated answer).

Comment: You also mentioned that this is a bug could you provide a link to the hibernate issue to prove it.